# SSIS - Concatenating and Lookups to create a string

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis

I am trying to combine many columns together to create a full string.

This is what I mean:

I have a table named QRFormats that looks like this:

```
| Id | Text1 | Variable1 | Text2 | Variable2 | Text3 | Variable3 |
| 1 | The Color | Color | Is designated | Description | *NULL* | *NULL* |
| 2 | The Company | Company| Is Located | Location| In Country | Country|
| 3 | The Part is | PartNumber| Work Order:| WorkOrder| *NULL* | CompanyCode |
.
.
```

The complete string should print the ***Text*** and lookup the ***Variable*** in completely different table using FK/PK correlations.

All the ***Variables*** are located in two possible tables called ***PartData*** and ***Company***

**PartData**

```
| Id | PartNumber | Color | WorkOrder | Description |
| 1 | 123456789 | Blue | 111222333 | Microchip |
| 2 | 101441414 | Silver | 55556666 | Handel |
```

**Company**

```
| Id | Company | Location | CompanyCode | Country |
| 1 | Microsoft | Seattle | 1234 | USA |
| 2 | Apple | California | 1122 | USA |
.
```

Some Examples of what I am trying to do....

.

**The *Complete* string should look as follows if my:**

-QRFormats FK is a 1:

-PartDataFK is a 1:

-Company FK is a 1:

***"The Color Blue Is designated Microchip"***

.

**The *Complete* string should look as follows if my:**

-QRFormats FK is a 2:

-PartDataFK is a 1:

-Company FK is a 3:

***"The Company Apple Is Located California In Country USA"***

.

**The *Complete* string should look as follows if my:**

-QRFormats FK is a 3:

-PartDataFK is a 2:

-Company FK is a 1:

***"The Part is 101441414 WorkOrder: 555566661234"***

.

Thank you very much for you help, I am using SSIS in VisualStudio 2015.

Comment: This seems like some left joins mixed with some case statements and basic string concatenation would work. What's your query so far?

Comment: Am am stuck at the very beginning of creating the complete sting. @wp78de

Comment: @Ben so far I am a bit l;ost on how to put this together. I started messing around with derived columns, but quickly realized I was in too deep.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have any consistency between sentences

Comment: @KeithL Only that I am using the different Fk's to define what the string should be.  I first start with the QRFormatFK to define what strinf format to use, then I use the PartDataFK and CompanyFK to define what the variables are.

Comment: I guess you are starting with 3 integers. go through 3 lookups to pull in the values and then use a derived column to piece it together

Comment: Thank you @KeithL, I have been able to use the lookups to pull in the values like you said, but I don't know how to piece it together in a derived column.  Do you have any examples I can follow?

Comment: I wish you made the DML. It's taking longer for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very interesting request. First the DML:

```
create table #QFR
(
     Id int
 ,   Text1  varchar(100)
 ,   Variable1 varchar(100)
 ,   Text2 varchar(100)
 ,   Variable2 varchar(100)
 ,   Text3 varchar(100)
 ,   Variable3 varchar(100) 

)

insert into #QFR
values
(   1,' The Color ','Color',' Is designated ','Description ',NULL ,NULL )
,(  2,' The Company ','Company',' Is Located ','Location',' In Country ','Country'  )
,(  3,' The Part is ','PartNumber','Work Order:','WorkOrder',NULL ,'CompanyCode'    )



create table #parts
(
    Id int
    ,    PartNumber varchar(100)
    ,    Color varchar(100)
    ,    WorkOrder varchar(100)
    ,    Description varchar(100)

)

insert into #parts
values
(1,'123456789','Blue ','111222333',' Microchip '),
(2,'101441414','Silver ','55556666',' Handel ')


create table #company
(
    Id int
    ,    Company varchar(100),
         Location varchar(100)
         ,   CompanyCode varchar(100)
         ,   Country varchar(100)

)

insert into #company
values
(1,' Microsoft ','Seattle ','1234',' USA ')
,(2,' Apple ','California ','1122',' USA ')
```

I create a CTE to flip the variable logic on its side and joined it in several times to make this work...

```
declare @qID int = 1
   ,@pID int = 1
   ,@cID int = 1

;with cte as
(
    select Label,Value
    from #parts
    cross apply (values('PartNumber',PartNumber),('Color',Color),('WorkOrder',WorkOrder),('Description',Description)) as a(Label,Value)
    where id =@pID 

    union all
    select Label,Value
    from #company
    cross apply (values('Company',Company),('Location',Location),('CompanyCode',CompanyCode),('Country',Country)) as a(Label,Value)
    where id =@cID
)

select Text1 , t1.Value , text2 , t2.Value , text3 , t3.Value
from #QFR q
    left join cte t1 on q.Variable1=t1.Label
    left join cte t2 on t2.Label = q.Variable2
    left join cte t3 on t3.label = q.Variable3
where q.id = @qID
```

Changed to a function:

```
create function fn_BuildAsentence (@qID int 
                                    ,@pID int
                                    ,@cID int)
returns varchar(max)
   as
BEGIN

declare @v varchar(Max)

;with cte as
(
    select Label,Value
    from parts
    cross apply (values('PartNumber',PartNumber),('Color',Color),('WorkOrder',WorkOrder),('Description',Description)) as a(Label,Value)
    where id =@pID 

    union all
    select Label,Value
    from company
    cross apply (values('Company',Company),('Location',Location),('CompanyCode',CompanyCode),('Country',Country)) as a(Label,Value)
    where id =@cID
)

select @v = concat(Text1 , t1.Value , text2 , t2.Value , text3 , t3.Value)
from QFR q
    left join cte t1 on q.Variable1=t1.Label
    left join cte t2 on t2.Label = q.Variable2
    left join cte t3 on t3.label = q.Variable3
where q.id = @qID

return @v

END
```

Finally, I would use a SQL Source (I presume that you are doing this in a data flow to go somewhere)

```
Select dbo.fn_BuildAsentence(QFR,parts,company),QFR,parts,company
from [whereever]
```

Comment: Thank you @KeithL, any idea how I can apply this to a SSIS package?  Is the best method just to drop in a SQL query within the SSIS and copy/paste this into that?

Comment: how many results do expect? For example, how many combinations are you doing and how do you determine them?

Comment: I am thinking i would turn this into a function and then call that with your 3 values

Comment: The first time I run this package I expect around 15,000 records.  After that I would expect about 10 or so each time the package is run.  There will be around 25 possible combinations of QRFormats and the combination is predetermined by the user who inputs the QRFormat ID to the record.

Comment: I added how to convert to a function as well as how to access the function. That is how I would accomplish this.

Comment: Awesome, thank you @KeithL.  Only, how do I add the function to SSIS?  Through an OLE DB Command?  Which then leads to how do I call this function for each record once I have used the Lookup to find all the ID's

Comment: you add that to the database not in ssis. run the create command in SSMS

Comment: what do I need to fill in as the [whereever] field?

Comment: QRFormatsFK, PartDataFK, and CompanyFK are all stored in the cache from completed SSIS lookups.  Will I need to dump these to a staging table to then pull into this function? @KeithL

Comment: can you put an image of your data flow? and possibly an image of the data viewer at run time showing the fields that you are using as keys? Sounds like you may need a SQL task with output.